# Pegar url com Javascript sem o GET

Tags: javascript

Estou pegando minha url assim:

```
var url = window.location.href;
```

Tenho o seguinte retorno: http://localhost/financeiro/pages/lancamentos.php?local=Iguacu.

Mas eu não quero a parte do GET, queria obter a url assim:
http://localhost/financeiro/pages/lancamentos.php

Como poderia fazer?

Comment: Qual o motivo disso?  De qualquer forma, para não ter os parâmetros na url, envie pelo método POST. Ou pretende apenas extrair a url sem parâmetros? Se for o caso invoque a propriedade `pathname`. ex: `window.location.pathname`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tenta pegar só o path

```
var url = window.location.pathname
```

Comment: Ops, verdade,era exatamente o pathname que deveria ter usado.